# Prices table - show individual user prices - contextual filters?

Tags: views

Have spent many hours searching web for an answer with no luck...

**I have:** PRODUCTS (many) and USERS (many) each user has his own price for each product.

**I need:**

- generate price table to edit prices (products are rows columns are users),
- generate personal prices table for each user (a tab on his account page)
- add new products and users with minimal amount of work

Right now I have a content type PRODUCT with fields for prices for each user.
And I don't know how to generate personal price lists for each user an their profile page. **Can I use contextual filter to show just one column from big prices table?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oskar :)

Comment: nobody...? is it so complicated or so simple? ;)

Comment: I guess it's not complicated nor simple, just broad. I would go with my own custom module here - and it hardly is an answer, is it? But I can't simply go and write that module for you... so I have nothing to tell.